# How to remove unneeded files after those are installed by Yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to create a recipe for a custom library in Yocto. I'm currently getting this error:

```
ERROR: ... do_package: QA Issue: pot-plugin: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /usr/lib/qt5/plugins/mediaservice/a.so.1.0
  /usr/lib/qt5/plugins/mediaservice/a.so.1
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
```

I already set those in `FILES_${PN}` but in that case Yocto complains about those being so symlinks, and that do not belong to the package. The proper thing would actually be to remove those also from the sysroot itself. I'm therefore trying to define the `do_install` step but I cannot find how to remove those before the package is created. I did something like:

```
do_install {
   rm <some_path>/a.so.1.0
   rm <some_path>/a.so.1
}
```

but I cannot find the proper path to use. Someone who can explain if this is the proper way to solve the issue and, in case it is, what path I should use to delete those files after those are installed and before the package is being created? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$D` contains the path to the installroot so you can write

```
do_install_append() {
    rm -f ${D}/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/mediaservice/a.so.1.0 ...
}
```

But you probably want to replace `/usr/lib/qt5/plugins` by a variable too.  To do this, inspect existing variables with

```
bitbake <recipe> -e | less
```

Comment: Tried $D but not in do_install_append. Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @ensc - What about a situation that the recipe that installs the un-desired files already has its own implementation of the `do_install_append` and I do not want to "manually" intervine there? Is there some ADDITIONAL function that is called AFTER do_install_append, something like "do_install_post_append"? (if there is such method, then I think it will be the most "elegant" approach in terms of "BitBake inheritence mind set").

Comment: @GuyAvraham `_append` (or now `:append`) is a special operation and accumulates

Comment: @ensc - Thanks for the prompt reply! I'm not sure what exactly do you mean by "...and accumulates"? Does it mean that I can have the "original" ("base") recipe have its own `do_install_append` implementation (within `some-recipe.bb` file for example) and ALSO I can "add" to it my `do_install_append` in my "derived" recipe (`some-recipe.bbappend`) and BOTH of them will be executed where the first one is from the `.bb` recipe file and the second is from the `.bbappend` recipe file?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is actually a bug in your custom library: it shouldn't be installing versioned symlinks for a module.

If you're using `libtool` to build this then - IIRC - passing `-module` will stop it versioning.